# Como eu deixo as <li> uma ao lado da outra?

Tags: html, css

Olá, boa tarde, sou iniciante em front end e queria sabe como posso deixar as li uma ao lado da outra sem perder os estilos que elas já possuem, vou anexar como elas deveriam estar, como estão, e os códigos, obrigado!

[Como deveriam estar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn1uP.jpg)

[Como estão](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO4w7.jpg)

Código abaixo

```css
 <style>
body, 
.menu,
.sub-menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu,
.sub-menu {
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
}
.sub-menu {
    background: #F8F9FA;
}
.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #6ca2ab;
    font-family: "Montserrat", "Odoo Unicode Support Noto", sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li {
    float: left;
}
.menu > li:hover {
    


transition: 0.5s;

opacity: 0.7;
}
.menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}



    </style>
```

```html
<div class="menu-container">
        <ul class="menu clearfix">
            <li><a href="#" style="color:black;">PRODUTOS</a>
                <!-- Nível 1 -->
                <!-- submenu -->
                <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
                    <li><a href="#">COSTURÁVEIS</a>
                        &nbsp;
                        <!-- Nível 2 -->
                        <!-- submenu do submenu -->
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">NECESSAIRES</a>
                                &nbsp;
                                <!-- Nível 3 -->
                                <!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    
                                </ul><!-- submenu do submenu do submenu -->
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">MOCHILAS</a></li>
                            &nbsp;
                            <li><a href="#">BOLSAS E SACOLAS</a></li>
                            &nbsp;
                            <li><a href="#">MALAS</a></li>
                            &nbsp;
                            <li><a href="#">PASTAS</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- submenu do submenu -->
                <ul class="inline"></ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">BEBIDAS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">ESPORTES</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">LINHA SUSTENTÁVEL</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">CANECAS E COPOS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">DATAS COMEMORATIVAS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">FEIRAS E EVENTOS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">LAZER</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">INFANTIL</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">SQUEEZES</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">ESCRITÓRIO</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">MULTILASER</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">ESCRITA</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">FEMININO</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">MASCULINO</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">OUTROS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">CHAVEIROS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">TÉRMICOS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">TECNOLOGIA</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">ELETRÔNICOS</a></li>
                    &nbsp;
                    <li><a href="#">FERRAMENTAS</a></li>
                </ul>

                </ul><!-- submenu -->
            </li>
            
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: por que tá usando só `<li>`? https://www.htmlprogressivo.net/2013/10/Como-criar-tabelas-linhas-colunas-As-tags-table-tr-td.html

Comment: eu deveria estar usando algum outro elemento?

Answer (score -1):

Tenta dividir as **ul**'s e **li**'s em **div**'s separadas, cada qual com a quantidade de linhas que deve ser exibida conforme o exemplo que você deu.

O exemplo abaixo utiliza as class do Bootstrap, mas vai ajudar você a entender melhor a estrutura.

```
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
  <footer class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-5 py-5 my-5 border-top">
    <div class="col mb-3">
      <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 link-dark text-decoration-none">
        <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
      </a>
      <p class="text-muted">© 2022</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col mb-3">

    </div>

    <div class="col mb-3">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col mb-3">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col mb-3">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Features</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Pricing</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">FAQs</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```